# Python Requests Library - Scraping separate JSON and HTML responses from POST request

Tags: python, json, http, python-requests, screen-scraping

I'm new to web scraping, programming, and StackOverflow, so I'll try to phrase things as clearly as I can.

I'm using the Python requests library to try to scrape some info from a local movie theatre chain. When I look at the Chrome developer tools response/preview tabs in the network section, I can see what appears to be very clean and useful JSON:

However, when I try to use requests to obtain this same info, instead I get the entire page content (pages upon pages of html). Upon further inspection of the cascade in the Chrome developer tools, I can see there are two events called GetNowPlayingByCity: One contains the JSON info while the other seems to be the HTML.

[JSON Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSZSD.png)
[HTML Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQPS8.png)

**How can I separate the two and only obtain the JSON response using the Python requests library?**

I have already tried modifying the headers within requests.post (the Chrome developer tools indicate this is a post method) to include *"accept: application/json, text/plain, */*"* but didn't see a difference in the response I was getting with requests.post. As it stands I can't parse any JSON from the response I get with requests.post and get the following error:

"json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 4 column 1 (char 3)"

I can always try to parse the full HTML, but it's so long and complex I would much rather work with friendly JSON info. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share what you have already tried, including the  URL and desired output. And provided a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because the javascript the page sends to your browser is making a request to an API to get the json info about the movies.

You could either try sending the request directly to their API (see edit 2), parse the html with a library like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or you can use a dedicated scraping library in python. I've had great experiences with [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/). It is much faster than requests

Edit:

If the page uses dynamically loaded content, which I think is the case, you'd have to use [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) with the PhantomJS browser instead of requests. here is an example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "your url"
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# Then parse the html code here
```

Or you could [load the dynamic content with scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html)

I recommend the latter if you want to get into scraping. It would take a bit more time to learn but it is a better solution.

Edit 2:

To make a request directly to their api you can just reproduce the request you see. Using google chrome, you can see the request if you click on it and go to 'Headers':

[image: Getting the request info]

After that, you simply reproduce the request using the requests library:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://paste.the.url/?here='

response = requests.get(url)

content = response.content

# in my case content was byte string 
# (it looks like b'data' instead of 'data' when you print it)
# if this is you case, convert it to string, like so

content_string = content.decode()

content_json = json.loads(content_string)

# do whatever you like with the data
```

You can modify the url as you see fit, for example if it is something like `http://api.movies.com/?page=1&movietype=3` you could modify `movietype=3` to `movietype=2` to see a different type of movie, etc

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Sounds about right that there is probably some Javascript doing some additional requesting from the API. I was trying to do this without 3rd party libraries but I'll put my pride away and have a look at scrappy.

Comment: @Gabe Above I said I didn't know about trying to use their API directly, but I'm 99% sure it is legal and possible. You can reproduce the request with any library really. I will try to show you an example using chrome. If you find my reply useful don't forget to upvote, it means a lot